# Using Image Stitching for X,Y Pose Estimation in Quadrotor Navigation: Feasibility and Limitations

Tags: pose, image, drone, 2d-pose-estimate

I'm exploring the feasibility of inferring the x, y pose of robots without direct positional data but utilizing image stitching. Here's the scenario: I have multiple drones equipped with downward-facing cameras and sensors such as a barometer and magnetometer, providing height and yaw angle information respectively. However, I lack direct x, y positional data for these drones.

Considering the sensor data available (height, yaw angle), can I rely on image stitching among these drones to estimate their x, y pose? My aim is to leverage the stitched images to back-calculate the x, y coordinates for the robots.

I understand the basics of image stitching and the availability of sensor data for relative positional information. I am also aware of Simultaneous Localization and Mapping (SLAM) but I think using image stitching should be theoretically simpler. I'm curious about the feasibility and limitations of using this approach:

Considerations:

- Feature Matching: How reliable is feature matching between images
  captured by different drones?
- Scale and Perspective: Can stitched images provide accurate absolute
  positional information without known scales or reference points?
- Sensor Fusion and Calibration: What challenges might arise in
  integrating barometer and magnetometer data with image data for
  position estimation?
- Computational Complexity: How much computational overhead might be
  involved in extracting x, y pose from stitched images?
- Additionally, what potential limitations or challenges might I
  encounter while attempting to use image stitching exclusively for x,
  y pose estimation without direct positional information? Are there
  environmental factors or dynamic changes that could impact the
  accuracy and reliability of this approach?

Any insights, guidance, or suggested methodologies for using image stitching in this context would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!